# Is there a way to make an Airflow process start at the exact same time every week?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an airflow process that runs every Sunday at 12:00am. Is there a way to trigger this process exactly at the same time (absolute time) every week regardless of previous run duration or outcome. I see that the start time of the process keeps creeping forward to the point that after a couple of weeks it now gets triggered a full 16 hours later than the scheduled time. How do I make it start exactly at the same time regardless of the previous run outcome or whether previously triggerred manually or not (cron like behaviour) ?

Comment: Could you share some detail on the dag you have? I'm admittedly a little surprised that that isn't the default

Comment: It's a dag that sends out emails based on some logic at a certain time. We had some errors in the process earlier because of which we triggerred it manually several times on days other than scheduled. However, it does not seem to start on its originally scheduled time anymore and seems to start from the time it was triggerred manually.

Answer (score 0):

Add depends_on_past argument in your DAG's default_args, false value will make sure new dagruns will be created every interval without depending on the previous dagrun status:

```
'depends_on_past': False
```

It might not be necessary, but I recommend restart your scheduler after making this change.

Comment: I already had this parameter set in this particular dag. However now we have moved to cron like schedule intervals and a new start_date to see if it helps

Comment: I assume you used `@weekly` before cron like format? It is working correctly for my experience but in order to schedule in time different than midnight at every end of the week, you should use cron like format. Which version of airflow do you use?

Comment: No I was using timedelta(days=7) before this. I use airflow version 1.9.0